# Check for analyticity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Prove that $f(z)=|z|^4$ is differentiable but not analytic at $z=0$

**My Attempt :** $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} so |z|^4=(x^2+y^2)^2$

Now, we see that at $z=0$ all the four partial derivatives are equal to zero so CR equations are satisfied at z=0. also as $f(z)$ is differentiable at z=0 it must be continueous there.

So why is the given function not analytic at z=0 ? am i missing out on something ?

Comment: From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function): "The phrase "holomorphic at a point $z_0$" means not just differentiable at $z_0$, but differentiable everywhere within some neighborhood of $z_0$ in the complex plane."

Comment: @julien Worth as an answer. Would be +1 just for using holomorphic instead of analytic. Even though they are completely equivalent and interchangable.

Comment: @Kaster Yes. One great advantage of the word "holomorphic" is that it spares us the trouble of adding the word complex to analytic.

Comment: @julien so do you mean than $f(z)$ is not holomorphic in some neighbourhood of $z=0$ ?

Comment: Yes. CR is equivalent to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$. But $f(z)=|z|^4=z^2\overline{z}^2$. So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=2z^2\overline{z}\neq 0$ for $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @julien I have this doubt that according to cauchy's theorem, the sufficient condition for a given function to be analytic is that its four first order partial derivatives w.r.t x and y should exist, they should be continueous at that point and satisfy the CR equation. How is this given function breaching these condition ?

Comment: Aman, you're missing the subtle point we're trying to make. The Cauchy-Riemann equations only tell you where the function is complex differentiable. A function being analytic is a stronger condition than being complex differentiable. If a function is analytic, it is complex differentiable on an open set in $\mathbb{C}$, so there are a wealth of points in which is is complex differentiable. However, this function is only differentiable at ONE point (and a set of one point is a closed set in $\mathbb{C})$. Thus your function is not analytic by the very definition.

Comment: @cameronwilliams thanks for your kind reply !!
I am clear with the point that being analytic is a stronger condition and if a function is analytic at a point it means differentiability at that point as well as its neighbourhood. the question however doesn't mention that f(z) is not differentiable at any other point.It just wants us to show that the function is differentiable at z=0 but not analytic there. so probably there are points in the neighbourhood of z=0 at which the function is not analytic. i am not able to locate or visualise those points.

Comment: @cameronwilliams In previous commnt i have mentioned the cauchy's sufficient condition for a function be holomorphic. in that context can you explain which condition is being breached ?

Comment: I think it's the same underlying issue. Even if the first and second derivatives exist and are equal, it doesn't mean that the function is analytic. Cauchy's criterion only guarantees that the function is complex differentiable on the set of (x,y) (or $z$ if you prefer) for which the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold. You still need that the set of $z$ for which the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold is an open set.

Comment: But I gave you the reason why it does not fulfill CR outside of $0$ in my comment above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial point is that the CR equations

$$ 4x(x^2+y^2) = 0 \text{ and } 4y(x^2+y^2)=0 $$

are satisfied iff $x=y=0$. Therefore, elsewhere $f(z)$ fails the necessary (but not sufficient) condition for being differentiable, i.e., CR equations fail. Any open neighbourhood will contains points other than the origin for which the equations do not hold.

This is the same reasoning used to show that $|z|^2$ is differentiable only at the origin, and hence nowhere analytic.

Comment: That solved it !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Analytic (holomorphic) means that the function is differentiable on an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. A single point is not an open set, thus it is not analytic (holomorphic). The reason we care about about this property is that it allows us to write the function in a Taylor series and obtain interesting and important information about the function that way. Many results that work for holomorphic functions don't work for functions that are not differentiable on open sets solely because we cannot write such functions in a Taylor series. Cauchy's theorem and anything that results from it does not hold, for instance.

Comment: To be more precise, holomorphic (=complex analytic) means complex differentiable on an open set.

Comment: You're exactly right. I should have been a bit more precise with terminology.